# How to write data option in jQuery.ajax() function when it include in a php mysql_query?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to add a comment system after my article,

php part code

```
<?php
...
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($resultset))
{
$article_title = $result['article_title'];
...
?>
<form id="postform" class="postform">
<input type="hidden" name="title" id="title" value="<?=$article_title;?>" />
<input type="text" name="content" id="content" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="Submit" />
</form>
...
<?php
}
?>
```

ajax part:

```
$(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".Submit").click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);
var anyBlank = 0;
if(anyBlank == "0")
{
var title    = $("#title").val();
var content   = $("#content").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_post.php",
data: "title="+title+"&content="+content,
success: function(date_added){
if(date_added != 0)
{
structure = '<div class="comment_date_added">'+date_added+'</div><div id="comment_text"><div id="comment_content">'+content+'</div>';                   
$("#post_comment").prepend(structure);
}
});
});
```

ajax_post.php

```
echo $title;
echo $content;//get $title and $content and insert into database.
```

my question: `<form id="postform" class="postform">` is written into a MYSQL_QUERY result circle.  how to modify ajax part so that every `div.submit` can post its own value to `ajax_post.php` and then return the data into `$("#post_comment").prepend(structure);` Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the input fields a *class* instead of an *ID*. IDs have to be unique in an HTML document:

```
<form class="postform">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" class="title" value="<?=$article_title;?>" />
    <input type="text" name="content" class="content" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you can make the data lookup relative to the clicked element:

```
var title = $(this).siblings('.title').val();
var content = $(this).siblings('.content').val();
```

I also suggest to pass an object to the `data` attribute for automatic URL encoding of the values:

```
data: {title: title, content: content}
```

Then, when you create a new entry for the `#post_comment` section, you have to give these elements also a class instead of an ID (and don't forget to use `var`!):

```
var structure = '<div class="comment_date_added">'+date_added+'</div><div class="comment_text"><div class="comment_content">'+content+'</div>';
```

or more jQuery like:

```
$('<div />', {class:'comment_data_added'})
.append($('<div />', {class: 'comment_date_added', text: date_added}))
.append($('<div />', {class: 'comment_content', text: content}))
.prependTo('#post_comment');
```

**Further notes:**

- You have somehow a nested `ready()` handler:

  ```
  $(function($) {                     //   <--┐
      $(document).ready(function(){   //   <--┴- this is the same
          //...
      });
  });
  ```

  Either do:

  ```
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(function($) {
      $('.Submit')...
  )};
  ```

  or

  ```
  $(function() {
      $('.Submit')...
  )};
  ```
- This part in the click handler:

  ```
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
  var parent = $(this);
  var anyBlank = 0;
  ```

  does not seem to do anything. Besides that, the `submit` button has no ID and no `name`.
- Depending on the further structure of your PHP code, you should have a look at the [*alternative syntax for control structures*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). It makes easier to mix PHP and HTML without fiddling around with brackets.

Comment: I am back for a lunch. I have follow the your instruction, I change `id` to `class` , remove the unnecessary code. but when I add `$(this).siblings` in the line `var title = $(this).siblings('.title').val(); var content = $(this).siblings('.content').val();`, the data will empty. and I remove the `$(this).siblings`, it can still post the first `.Submit` data to the database.   still need help.

Comment: @cj333: Is the form structure exactly as you posted? `$(this).siblings('.title')` will find the element with class `title` that is at the same level as the submit button. Alternatively, you can try `$(this).closest('form').find('.title').val()`.

Comment: yes the form structure is exactly as my posted. I tried `$(this).closest('form').find('.title').val()` ,this can send data to each form. but the display still has problem, I tried two of your method, add `var` or jquery like, but when I post a comment in anywhere, it will be created 10 times in all the `<div class="post_comment"></div>` if my mysql query have 10 result articles. (I have changed all the id into class)